# I would like to mask my svg with my background parent container

Tags: html, jquery, css

```css
#sine_wave {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  /* Adjust the height as needed */
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}

#sine_wave svg {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(green, green), linear-gradient(green, green), linear-gradient(green, green), linear-gradient(green, green), linear-gradient(green, green), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
  -webkit-mask-size: 5% 100%, 5% 100%, 100% 5%, 100% 5%, 80% 80%;
  -webkit-mask-position: left top, right top, center top, center bottom, center center;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="sitecrumble">
  <div class="crack-top">
    <div id="sine_wave">
      <svg width="1000" height="1000">
    </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="crack-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Here is an image visual: https://imgur.com/Gnjz8fx

I am trying to mask my background color with the sine waves.

So the green color should not be visible in the top half of the container.

I'm not too familiar with this, how can I achieve it?

Comment: I don't know about SVGs, but you can do this with pure CSS. https://css-generators.com/wavy-shapes/ can generate the mask code for you.

Comment: @JosephWebber what the heck? Wow. Thanks, just what I needed.